# Why do I have to add main-menu under features[] in the theme info file?

Tags: .info

I have seen other themes that just define regions and then use drupals theme() function in the **page.tpl.php** to print the Main menu wherever the developer pleases.

This was not the case for me, and I spent a lot of time figuring out that for some reason I had to both add '**features[] = main_menu**' into the theme .info file, as well as going to '*admin/appearance/settings/themename*' and enable the feature before it will display.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case, and hope someone can elucidate or at least point me towards some enlightening documentation.  Thanks.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? Are you using a base theme or editing a contrib theme, or is your theme completely custom?

Comment: This is my first attempt at creating a theme from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The `features` elements in the .info file are used to add or suppress Drupal core/global theme settings. If you add *any* `features` options to your .info file, you must add *all* of the options you wish to have available to your theme. All of the options are included by default if no `features` options are added to the theme's .info file.

If you want to set the default setting for any of these features to your theme's .info file, you can use the `setting` entry. For example, if you wanted to default the "main_menu" option to be on, you would add this to .info:

```
setting[toggle_main_menu] = 1
```

More information on all of these topics can be found in the [drupal.org Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/node/171205)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link, but I don't understand why I have been forced to declare my features to begin with. Why aren't these core features available to my theme out of the box?

Comment: If you add *no* core features to your .info file, then they will all be available, unless you have a base theme that has stripped them out somehow. Also, if you have added any customizations to theme-settings.php in your theme, it is possible that you may have inadvertently effected these core features.

Comment: I have not edited the theme-settings.php, and there was no base theme used, yet they appear stripped out.

Comment: According to the documentation, if you have **no** lines in your theme's .info file that begin with `features` then all of the core theme settings should be available to your theme. It is possible that you are using the wrong code in your page.tpl.php file to print out the main menu or there are a dozen other factors that could be in play. It is impossible to know what the cause is without having direct access to your theme and site, but analyzing your specific theme runs outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but how is that outside the scope of Drupal Answers? I could easily create a post showing all of these things and linking to the text of the files.

Comment: Depending on how it's worded, it could be considered too localized. Mostly I added that warning because a lot of times people take "would need to see your site..." as an invitation to stalk out my personal email and send me a link and admin login to their site :)